# Error on generating genesis.block and channel.tx in sequence using separate configtx.yaml files

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

**Error from docker logs:** `Existing config does not contain element for [Groups] /Channel/Application`

**The configtx.yaml for generating genesis.block**

```
Profiles:

OrgsOrdererGenesis:
    Orderer:
        <<: *OrdererDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *OrdererOrgs
    Consortiums:
        SampleConsortium:
            Organizations:
```

Organizations:

```
- &OrdererOrgs
    Name: orderer0
    ID: orderer0
    MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/test.com/msp
    AdminPrincipal: Role.Admin
```

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
    OrdererType: solo

```
Addresses:
     - orderer0:7050
BatchTimeout: 2s
MaxChannels: 0
```

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    Organizations:

**The configtx.yaml for generating channel.tx**

```
Profiles:

OrgsChannel:
    Consortium: SampleConsortium
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *org
```

Organizations:

```
- &org
    Name: org
    ID: org
    MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org.org.com/msp
    AdminPrincipal: Role.Admin

    AnchorPeers:
        - Host: peer0
          Port: 7051
```

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    Organizations:

Is this a valid scenario where we can generate genesis.block first [without specifying organization details] and then finally creating channel.tx by specifying org details?

Comment: Did you find a solution?